# FileOutputStream is really slow

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am downloading databases from the network, which are between 100 Kbytes and 500 Kbytes large. Here is my code (removed useless code):

```
URLConnection uConnection = downloadUrl.openConnection();
InputStream iS = uConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bIS = new BufferedInputStream(iS);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
FileOutputStream fOS = new FileOutputStream(db);
int bufferLength = 0;
while ((bufferLength = bIS.read(buffer)) > 0) {
fOS.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
}
fOS.close();
```

My problem is, that it takes a long time for him to finish the while-statement. Have I messed up the code somewhere? It shouldn't take that long for such small files, shouldn't it? I'm talking about 1 minute, for three files not larger than 1 MB altogether... Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with `FileOutputStream`? The problem could just as easily be bandwidth for downloading your data. Have you used something like Traceview to determine exactly where you are spending your time?

Comment: I don't know what Traceview is. I debugged the code and it's because of the while-statement that it is really slow. I also thought, that the download of the data is done when my InputStream-Object is instanciated. Or is it not downloaded there?

Comment: using a buffer size of 1024 is IMHO a bad idea. In a Smartphone all media typically have a block-size of 4096 bytes or larger (e.g. SD-Card).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Thank you. Your were right about it. It is the bandwidth that's making the write-method so slow.

Answer (score 4):

"Slow" is really rather ambiguous. That being said, considering what you're trying to do you shouldn't be using a `BufferedInputStream` and your `buffer` is way too small.

The buffered wrappers are for optimizing small reads/writes. Since all you're doing is trying to read a ton of data as fast as you can, you should just read directly from the `InputStream`, and use a large buffer (Say, 64k since the underlying native code is probably going to chunk at that size anyway).

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
...
while ((bufferLength = iS.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) > 0) {
    ...
```

Comment: I'll try that. Is there good online literature about Java I/O? It kind of confuses me alot :)

Comment: I'd have to google around, but this isn't specific to Java. Think of it this way - if you had to move a bunch of water from once place to another which would be faster; using a 16oz cup or a 5gal bucket? With that small buffer you're having to fill and empty it a whole lot more times which has a cost. The buffered wrapper is for when you know you're going to need a bunch of water, but only want to deal with it a cup at a time. It pre-fetches the bucket and lets you take cup-fulls from it. When the bucket is empty, it refills it.

Comment: I was thinking about your answer the past days and I wondered: Why do many people create byte arrays with smaller sizes then the one you've provided me in your answer if it's slower?

Comment: As a general practice, you only allocate the buffer size you need. Why waste memory? If you're not doing what you're doing (simply shuffling data between two streams) you only need to allocate a buffer that is big enough for the data you want to work on at any given time. If they *are* doing what you're doing ... you were using a small buffer too until someone explained why a bigger one was better ;)

Answer (score -3):

I've found the real solution in **Jdk 1.7**, which is made by reliable, fast, simple and almost definitively will spawn a pity veil on older java.io solutions.Despite the web is still plenty full of examples of copying files in java using In/out Streams I'll warmely suggest everyone to use *a simple method* : **java.nio.Files.copy(Path origin, Path destination)** with optional parameters for replacing destination,migrate metadata file attributes and even try a transactional move of files (if permitted by the underlying O.S.). That's a really good Job, waited for so long! You can easily convert code from *copy(File file1, File file2)* by appending a "*.toPath()*" to the File instance (e.g. *file1.toPath(), file2.toPath()*. Note also that the boolean method **isSameFile(file1.toPath(), file2.toPath())**, is already used inside the above copy method but easily usable in every case you want. For every case you can't upgrade to 1.7 using community libraries from Apache (commons-io) or Google (guava commons) is still suggested.

Comment: And what does that have to do with reading data from a socket and writing it to a file?